# How to stratify sampling for R random forest regression

Tags: r, random-forest

I have an imbalanced time series dataset in which older cohorts have more observations than newer cohorts. I'm trying to use `strata` and `sampsize` in R's `randomForest` function to downsample the older cohorts in order to build a regression model. However, my attempt is resulting in the error "sampsize should be of length one".

Below is my code. I start by building a sample imbalanced dataset with two predictors and a little noise added.

```
#Create data frame in which older cohorts have more observations
date <- c(seq.Date(as.Date('2016-01-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"),
  seq.Date(as.Date('2016-02-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"),
  seq.Date(as.Date('2016-03-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"),
  seq.Date(as.Date('2016-04-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"),
  seq.Date(as.Date('2016-05-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"),
  seq.Date(as.Date('2016-06-01'), as.Date('2016-10-01'), "month"))

cohort <- factor(c(rep(1,10),rep(2,9),rep(3,8),rep(4,7),rep(5,6),rep(6,5)))

set.seed(10)
x1 <- 1:10 + rnorm(10)
x2 <- sin(10) + rnorm(10)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(10)

set.seed(1)
x1noise2 <- rnorm(9, 0, .1)
x1noise3 <- rnorm(8, 0, .1)
x1noise4 <- rnorm(7, 0, .1)
x1noise5 <- rnorm(6, 0, .1)
x1noise6 <- rnorm(5, 0, .1)

x1 <- c(x1, x1[2:10]+x1noise2, x1[3:10]+x1noise3, x1[4:10]+x1noise4, x1[5:10]+x1noise5, x1[6:10]+x1noise6)

set.seed(2)
x2noise2 <- rnorm(9, 0, .1)
x2noise3 <- rnorm(8, 0, .1)
x2noise4 <- rnorm(7, 0, .1)
x2noise5 <- rnorm(6, 0, .1)
x2noise6 <- rnorm(5, 0, .1)

x2 <- c(x2, x2[2:10]+x2noise2, x2[3:10]+x2noise3, x2[4:10]+x2noise4, x2[5:10]+x2noise5, x2[6:10]+x2noise6)

set.seed(3)
ynoise2 <- rnorm(9, 0, .1)
ynoise3 <- rnorm(8, 0, .1)
ynoise4 <- rnorm(7, 0, .1)
ynoise5 <- rnorm(6, 0, .1)
ynoise6 <- rnorm(5, 0, .1)

y <- c(y, y[2:10]+ynoise2, y[3:10]+ynoise3, y[4:10]+ynoise4, y[5:10]+ynoise5, y[6:10]+ynoise6)

df <- data.frame(date, cohort, x1, x2, y)

#Plot of data shown below
plot(df$date, df$y, col=df$cohort)

#Build random forest models
library(randomForest)
set.seed(4)
rf1 <- randomForest(y~x1+x1, data=df) #This works
set.seed(4)
rf2 <- randomForest(y~x1+x1, data=df, strata=df$cohort, sampsize=rep(4,6)) #This results in error saying 'sampsize should be of length one'
```

[image: Plot of target variable by date colored by cohort]

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a specific programming question; it seems like a program about statistical modeling. Such questions belong on [stats.se] or [datascience.se], not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can post on Cross Validated too. The specific programming question is how to do this in R, since my attempt is resulting in an error.

Comment: If this is really all about an error message, you should make that more clear in the question. But questions about what's "recommended" as far as data analysis goes do not belong here.